# Ошибка при удалении пакетов Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint, apt

Воспользовался этой инструкцией
https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-focal/
Теперь не могу очистить систему и поставить нормальную версию mysql проблемы с зависимостями.
Из той инструкции самое главное что я сделал это

```
wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb

sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
```

Теперь при удалении такая ошибка.

```
sudo apt remove mysql*
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Невозможно найти пакет mysql-apt-config_0.8.12-1_all.deb
```

Если удалять по одному пакету то все нормально.

Comment: Забавный конфигуратор репозиториев. Ради интереса установил на виртуалке. Снес sudo apt purge mysql-apt-config

Comment: Удалился пакет, но ошибка при такой команде осталось. Не подскажите, откуда он может брать имя пакета, и как от него избавиться?

Comment: Если Вы хотите удалить пакеты со всеми настройками-конфигурацией - используйте sudo apt purge. Видимо mysql-apt-config подлинковался в /var/lib/apt/lists/ Попробуйте sudo su apt-get update apt-get -f install apt --fix-broken install Лучше всего отрабатывает sudo dpkg -l| grep -v 'ii'| less Почитайте здесь https://debianforum.ru/index.php?topic=9178.0

Comment: Забыл добавить sudo apt-get autoclean - удалили пакет, избавится от установленных по зависимости пакетов. sudo apt-get autoremove - удаляет неудалённые зависимости от уже удалённых пакетов. Каламбур